# Docker exec rm not working

Tags: docker

I want to remove a file in my docker through `docker exec`:

```
user@mongo:~$ docker exec 765511b2869e rm -rf /backup/*.zip
user@mongo:~$ docker exec 765511b2869e ls /backup
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40103038 Mar 13 15:26 backup-20170313.zip
```

Apparently it is not working.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the wildcard (*)

Comment: The reason is because it's being treating like: `rm -rf '/backup/*.zip'`, where the asterisk is a literal character.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Characters like * are interpreted by the shell. Thus you need to invoke a shell for them to work.

```
docker exec 765511b2869e sh -c 'rm -rf /backup/*.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about this one